# How to receive object using Spring jmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

Here's my use case:

1. RESTFul calls a service to create a message in a jms queue using jmsTemplate:

   ```
   @Autowired
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
   public void sendMessage(final ApplicationContext appContext) {
       jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
           @Override
           public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
           ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(appContext);
           return objectMessage;
       }
   });
   }
   ```
2. An other RESTFul calls a service to get the message from the queue using:

   ```
   public ApplicationContext getMessage(final ApplicationContext appContext) {
       Object wObj = jmsTemplate.receive(MessagingConfiguration.NAMED_QUEUE);
       return (ApplicationContext)wObj;
   }
   ```

As you can read, it is quite simple. I know I can use asynchronuous listeners with @JmsListener annotation but I need to synchronise the receive action. When I try this code, I get a class cast exception (which makes sens). My question: how do I convert the message (ActiveMQObjectMessage) to my POJO (ApplicationContext)?

Stacktrace:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ApplicationContextManager] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to com.tigidou.commons.appcontext.model.ApplicationContext] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage cannot be cast to com.tigidou.commons.appcontext.model.ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert the JMS message to your POJO (application specific Object)If yes, then the following might be your help.

The package org.springframework.jms.support.converter provides a MessageConverter abstraction to convert between Java objects and JMS messages.

Something on the same lines:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11863662/7269013

Comment: I have tried what is proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11863662/7269013 but I get this error:

javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.tigidou.commons.appcontext.model.ApplicationContext! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload.

Comment: [link] (http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html) explains how to include pojo serialization in JMS (ActiveMQ). This does not return errors.

Added: 
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
  connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
  connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.desjardins.assurancedommages.commons"));

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Based on error message that contains the link to http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html. I have changed the following on my configuration of the connection factory (add trusted package):

```
@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.tigidou.commons"));
    return connectionFactory;
}
```